# Understanding Mac OS X indexing using “mdutil -E -i off /”

Tags: macos, bash, search-indexing

Two questions about [`mdutil`](http://eloper.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdutil.1.html) and indexing:

- What is the `-E` option?  It seems to me that it means something like "reindex" however the following bash command does not make sense to me `mdutil -E -i off /`.
- Can you run `mdutil` on some arbitrary folder in your system and it will index recursively all subfolders, and nothing else on your system?

I have the general idea on `mdutil` but I'm just a little confused by the [`man mdutil`](http://eloper.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdutil.1.html) explanation of `-E`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the man page for [`mdutil`](http://manpagez.com/man/1/mdutil) states; bold emphasis is mine:

> The `mdutil` command is useful for managing the metadata stores **for
> mounted volumes**.

So when you ask:

> Can you run `mdutil` on some arbitrary folder in your system and it will
> index recursively all subfolders, and nothing else on your system?

Nope, since `mdutil` is *not a folder-based metadata storage tool*, but rather a *volume-based metadata storage tool*.

Then you say:

> What is the `-E` option?  It seems to me that it means something like
> "reindex" however the following bash command does not make sense to me
> `mdutil -E -i off /`.

The `-E` option in the man page is described as:

> This flag will cause each local store for the volumes indicated to be
> erased. The stores will be rebuilt if appropriate.

So the `-E` option simply erases a metadata store on a specified volume.  And in the case of this example:

```
mdutil -E -i off /
```

That command will erase (via the `-E` option) the metadata store on the volume mounted at root (`/`) and then turn off the indexing status (via the `-i off` option) on the volume mounted at root (`/`) as well.

Your confusion might come from the fact that `/` doesn’t *seem* like an explicit volume name, but rather a path. But that `/` does indicate the root volume of the booted OS you are running that command on.

For example, let’s look at the output for `ls -la /Volumes/` on an example Mac OS X system. It might look something like this:

```
drwxrwxrwt@  7 root  admin   238 Sep  3 19:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root  wheel  1054 Sep  3 01:40 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 jack  admin  6148 May 18 18:57 .DS_Store
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     1 Sep  3 10:17 Hard Drive -> /
```

Note how `Hard Drive` is not actually a “real” mounted volume as much as it is a symbolic link to the `/` mounted volume on the file system. The true mounted volume name is `/`.

So knowing that `/` and `Hard Drive` both point to the same mounted volume this command using the full `/Volumes/` name:

```
mdutil -E -i off /Volumes/Hard\ Drive/
```

is effectively the same command as this on the same Mac OS X system:

```
mdutil -E -i off /
```

Comment: Thank you.  You are right part of my confusion is muddling the idea of paths, mounted volumes, and the "Hard Drive".  And its obvious that E eases the metadata...  Idk why I was confused XD.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - On the -E option, can you clarify the second part - *The stores will be rebuilt if appropriate.* Does it mean that after erasing it will also rebuild / recreate the metadata store, implying that it is only erased only if indexing is also turned off?